# Unexpected token when lazy loading components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, babeljs

I'm attempting to refactor a growing React App to use lazy loading. Taking the following as an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const Orders = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./Orders'),
    loading() {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
});
```

My webpack compile always fails with:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token
...
> 24 |   loader: () => import('./Orders'),
```

It's clearly the import that is choking the code, but I don't understand why.

My `.babelrc` file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Comment: What webpack version do you use?

Comment: does it work if you use `require` instead of `import`?

Comment: The `import(...)` syntax is [Stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import), are you sure you have the necessary options/plugins for it to work in your setup?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk 4.6

Comment: @riwu I don't think this will work, I need to use import

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I suspect you are right, but I'm not sure what I am missing from my setup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So following up on [T.J. Crowder's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075914/unexpected-token-when-lazy-loading-components#comment87167968_50075914) to my original question I found the [babel dynamic import plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import)

Installing this with yarn:

```
yarn add babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import -dev
```

Then adding it to my .babelrc, thus:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

fixed the `Unexpected token` issue.

Comment: yarn `save dev` function is used adding a `-D` at the end of the line, not `-dev`